How to access my public server (setup via nginx proxy) through it's public domain but as a LAN connection?
When I am on my local network (subnet?), I would like to go to sub1.myserver.com and for it to work the same as going to 192.168.1.99:1234 - i.e. the goal would be to use the same domain name I also use publicly for this server while getting e.g. LAN download speeds.
My Setup:
I have multiple services running running on different ports, i.e.: 192.168.1.99:1234 and 192.168.1.99:5678 on my Debian Bookworm server.
My DNS (porkbun) has A records for my public ip -> (sub)domain names.
And I have an nginx proxy doing proxy_pass'es like sub1.myserver.com -> 0.0.0.0:1234 and sub2.myserver.com -> 0.0.0.0:5678.
This works great and I can access my server publicly via sub1.myserver.com.
I can also, of course, go to 192.168.1.99:1234 directly and connect to the same application via LAN.
How could I achieve re-using the same domain for local lan connections, and if not possible/not advisible, what would be the next best solution?

Update after trying yagmoth555's answer:
So, my SoHo router (DrayTek Vigor2766ax) can indeed do NAT loopback ("Port Redirection"). However, since that makes all traffic go through the router, it completely chokes out its CPU, so I do not get 1000 Mbps speeds. Unless you have a business router, DNS server is probably more advisable.

So you have a NAT router - can it do hairpinning / NAT loopback?

@Bravo Yes, I believe so. I have a DrayTek Vigor2766 and, while it's very difficult to find whether they do, their Australian FAQ page says it does. (https://faq.draytek.com.au/docs/what-is-nat-loopback-is-it-supported-in-vigor-routers/)

You have two choices;
1 - A split-DNS scenario. You host an internal DNS server that will resolve the local IP to computers that use that DNS server. The public DNS would not change, but that make the zone to be duplicated locally with the one on the internet.
2 - Some business class router can do reverse NAT scenario. Its rules on the router that if a computer go to a specified public IP from the LAN, the router rewrite the packet to go on the local LAN IP. That scenario is more transparent to the user, even if they try to ping the dns's name.

Implement IPv6. Use the same globally unique addresses on the inside and the outside. Makes the same names on the inside and the outside trivial.
You would have your own large net to play in. Properly routed, hosts are on the local network with LAN speeds, they just happen to have globally routable IP addresses.
Say the reverse proxy is 2001:db8:116:8524::99.   Backend servers  could be host1 as 2001:db8:116:8524::443:1  Additional hosts 2 and 3, repeat for however many you need.  Put all of these as names in DNS, AAAA records this time, and only need one zone for internet and internal.
Firewall as usual, preventing or allowing traffic to the internet and other zones as desired.
Can keep the design of a reverse proxy in front, name sub1 to host1 or whatever you want.  Because you can have many IP addresses, you can have the port number the same across many services on many hosts.
If you wished to keep legacy IPv4 also, that is a little more difficult. With a dual IP stack proxy in front, you can keep your public A records for sub1 and so on. But proxy them to the IPv6 backend addresses for simplicity.  From the LAN this might go out the WAN interface and back in, but if you wanted to avoid that use IPv6 internally.
